# CRM Dynamics Upsert - Insert OptionSet

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to update/Insert Contact Entity.  While simple text fields are saving, having difficulties updating OptionSet.  For ex. `new_gender` field is an option set (Male/Female).

```
contact["new_gender"] = new OptionSetValue(1); //Does not work
contact["new_gender"] = 1; //Does not work
```

Error says:

```
"new_gender should have the Integer value of Enum. Please supply it in the format - <entitysetname>(<attributename>=100000000)"
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: This is a custom error message. You have to check your code base and enum for this

Answer (score 0):

Custom OptionSets have a prefix named ***Option Value Prefix***. I guess in you case it's "10000".
Try it this way:

```
contact["new_gender"] = new OptionSetValue(100000001);
```

Comment: It didn't help.  It gives  this error message. "new_gender should have the Integer value of Enum. Please supply it in the format - <entitysetname>(<attributename>=100000000)". I guess the format should be as above.

Comment: what is the code Value for the Male and Female options?

Comment: I set the code value as 1 & 2.  There is no additional digits

Comment: what is the Option Value Prefix in the Publisher settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an Enum something like

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male = 10000001,
    Female = 10000002
}
```

and set the attribute of gender

```
contact["new_gender"] = new OptionSetValue((int)Gender.Male);
```

also, you can get the gender value like this;

```
int value = ((OptionSetValue)contact[new_gender]).Value;
```